# Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments error on generic custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using this generic hook to return previous props, it was working fine but all of a sudden it is giving "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments." error.

```
function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
    const ref = useRef<T>();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
}

const TestingContainer: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    ...
    usePrevious<Props>(props)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Try giving the `props` parameter in `TestingContainer` a type of `Props`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give to `props` param `Props` type

See [LIVE example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhnAXArgI1pAtHeBDATvcEYcASwDt4BTXAM2wGNLIAFXAewAc0BvKSf2GwC2lVpwBcWXOQDmAbnABfcKQrU6jSAFlEOZABtKAJUo0A8sgBWlevAA8AFQB8kXv371EuXJQqSHCsrgNIhktiRsZJCIsMamjk4AFOQk8CTY%20gBqGYiU-gCUkjp6hibmVjb2zgrBoeGR0bFldmJcSfmufPw%20SLhRQroWloEq9JEIkAPwQ0W62AZx5da2LextkAC8ne6Qnt6%208JJuO%206CIq2SAOQAjABMAMyXADRdkIovQeCgENBYKGiYXwAE0IxFqYTSDRioh8ADcIjEEolYTk8pAHIV0ZAAD7RMhA0zkShA7buYDASDkSBsXAE3CQeBsSAcbCwNAo-QkIHYSFkNBU%20AACxIaA4%20mwAE8ZOxQiCdmM%20fBID4aJtGoskRzcvkajtyZSojS6QymSy2ZAOVyeRE%20QaGcLReKpTL8a9QOqAKI0GiVRKJDobFzHE7K0wAOj2Pgoaq1lAUO0UOugYJ2PS8URVEa8UfgI3AComDkoCFkAGFIjgifStokOGtYJJWrAA0HXtDWJR4WxEU2knXOM2lOAgA) or code below

```
/**
 * stubs - start
*/
interface Props {
    someProp: string;
}

interface MutableRefObject<T> {
    current: T;
}

function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;

function useRef<Props>() {
    return mutObj;
}

const mutObj: MutableRefObject<Props> = {
    current: {
        someProp: '123',
    },
}


/**
 * stubs - end
*/

function usePrevious<T>(value: T): T | undefined {
    // in order to pass validations in this playground
    const ref = useRef<T>(value);

    // in order to pass validations in this playground
    /* useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    }); */

    return ref.current;
}

const TestingContainer = (props: Props) => {
    usePrevious<Props>(props)
}
```

---

Please, let me know if it works for you or not )